# How to create dynamically decorated (wrapped) functions that are pickable in python?

Tags: python, pickle, concurrent.futures

Basically, how to make the second one work. The use case is to wrap function and trap exceptions/add timings etc.

```
import concurrent.futures
import functools
def with_print(func):
    """ Decorate a function to print its arguments.
    """
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def my_func(*args, **kwargs):
        print("LOOK", args, kwargs)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return my_func

def f():
    print('f called')

g = with_print(f)

executor = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=10)

tasks = [f for x in range(10)]
fut = list()
for task in tasks:
    fut.append(executor.submit(task))
res = [x.result() for x in fut]
print(res)


# THIS ONE FAILS
tasks = [g for x in range(10)]
fut = list()
for task in tasks:
    fut.append(executor.submit(task))
res = [x.result() for x in fut]
print(res)
```

Error is:

_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle : it's not the same object as **main**.f

Comment: Try putting all of your code starting with `executor = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=10)` on down in a block that begins with if  \_\_name\_\_  ==  '\_\_main\_\_':. Otherwise every subprocess will try to start 10 more subprocesses and you will get into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the inner function outside the decorator function and use the fact that `functools.partial` is pickleable:

```
import concurrent.futures
import functools


def inner_with_print(*args, func=None, **kwargs):
    print("LOOK", args, kwargs)
    return func(*args, **kwargs)


def with_print(func):
    result_func = functools.partial(inner_with_print, func=func)
    return functools.wraps(func)(result_func)


def f(arg, kwarg):
    print("f called")


g = with_print(f)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        [executor.submit(g, i, kwarg=i) for i in range(10)]

# LOOK (0,) {'kwarg': 0}
# called
# LOOK (1,) {'kwarg': 1}
# f called
# ...
```

Metadata was copied correctly:

```
print(vars(g))
# {'__module__': '__main__', '__name__': 'f', '__qualname__': 'f', '__doc__': None, '__annotations__': {}, '__wrapped__': <function f at 0x7f3251f01430>}
```

EDIT: the above works, but it looks like it's not an issue with dynamic decorators. Everything works fine if you change `g = with_print(f)` to `f = with_print(f)`. It looks like pickle looks for `__main__.f` dynamically and it finds `g`, as a result of `functools.wraps` magic.

EDIT2: the `functools.wraps` magic is actually setting `__qualname__` to `f`. If you set it back to `g` then it works fine:

```
g.__qualname__ = "g"
```

It looks like all of this is happening, because you used `wraps`, but also changed the function name to `g`.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61490167/how-to-fix-or-reorganize-this-multiprocessing-pattern-to-avoid-pickling-errors what I finally ended up doing.