# How to fix or reorganize this multiprocessing pattern to avoid pickling errors?

Tags: python, pickle, concurrent.futures

Another pickling question ... The following leads to pickling errors. I think it is to do with the scoping or something. Am not sure yet.

The goal is to have a decorator that takes arguments and enriches a function with methods. If the best way is to simply construct classes explicitly then that is fine but this is meant to hide things from users writing "content".

```
import concurrent.futures
import functools

class A():
    def __init__(self, fun, **kwargs):
        self.fun = fun
        self.stuff = kwargs
        functools.update_wrapper(self, fun)
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(self.stuff, args, kwargs)
        return self.fun(*args, **kwargs)

def decorator(**kwargs):
    def inner(fun):
        return A(fun, **kwargs)
    return inner

@decorator(a=1, b=2)
def f():
    print('f called')

executor = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=10)

tasks = [f for x in range(10)]
fut = list()
for task in tasks:
    fut.append(executor.submit(task))
res = [x.result() for x in fut]
print(res)
```

Error is:

```
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function f at 0x7fe37da121e0>: it's not the same object as __main__.f
```

Comment: I think either need to refactor to have functions defined statically at the top level scopr or use dill to dumps the functions and dill.loads remotely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing something like this:

```
def dill_wrapped(dilled, *args, **kwargs):
    fun = dill.loads(dilled)
    return wrapped(fun, *args, **kwargs)
```

You should probably try hard to avoid the need for this but you really do need it sometimes when decorating functions.